# What is the best approach to fix empty pockets in a concrete slab/wall

Tags: civil-engineering

What is the best approach to fix the pockets seen below:

[image: wall_air_pocket]
[image: hole]
[image: some_other_pocket_in_same_spot]

The pockets were due to the stones in place which did not allow to pass the concrete material, and later on gravity made it's way.

Options on my head:

- Fill with liquid cement, although it won't be as tough.
- Fill with concrete, can't guarantee it will make it into every spot of the air pocket, nor sure how to do it well without failing miserably.
- Fill with liquid cement and little pieces of rock (one of the 3 components that concrete uses) so it can fill as much as possible and the pieces of rock can fill the big part.

Cutting down the affected parts are not an option.

Comment: If this is load-bearing then bodging it is not a safe option... Do the job properly.

Comment: As implied by Solar Mike's comment, we need to know what we're actually looking at. What sort of structure is this? Are those beams, columns, or other structurally relevant objects? Also, how did there come to be such absurdly large stones in the concrete in the first place?

Comment: There is a technology of injection of special high-strength cement, creating firm anchors and reinforcing the whole structure. It's frequently used in historical buildings renovation, so this is where you should look for help.

Comment: While you're at it, check the rebar for corrosion (on center pic it looks good, could be some on right pic but we can't be sure from these pics alone)

Comment: Thanks all. atmart corroded part had the sustaining boards and during the days of watering it got corroded because there was no cement. atSF that sounds awesome I will certainly look at that. at Solar Mike and atWasabi yes it was supposed to hold a Durock wall. I have never worked in construction so this was officially my first DIY job. The stones you see were to save a bit of concrete for other parts I needed.
atSolar Mike yup the job sucks , they agree with you here ->  https://www.diychatroom.com/f105/what-best-approach-fix-empty-pockets-concrete-slab-wall-655813/#post5796421